# Is HBase block cache dropped when restart HBase?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hbase

I am currently confused with the HBase block cache.

I have come to aware about the existence of HBase block cache and it is for read performance. The question is that, if I stop the HBase by command,

`stop-hbase.sh`

and **restart** HBase by command,

`start-hbase.sh`

would it cause dropping all the block caches of HBase and block caches become empty?

Thank you all for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's right. HBase BlockCache is instantiated at region server startup and is retained for the entire lifetime of the process.

If you restart the deamons, you are going to have an empty block cache due to the region server is created again. The data which is always saved is the data which is stored in HFiles.

Comment: I think when I restart HBase including region server daemons, it rebuild blockcache in region server memory, because throughput does not change. Is there any way to manually drop the blockcache of HBase?

Comment: I don't know how to delete the block cache during region server execution. What i do know is you can disabled the block cache function when create a column family. For example you can `create 't1', {NAME => 'f1', VERSIONS => 1, TTL => 2592000, BLOCKCACHE => true}`

Comment: Also, you can do the same thing when using a java running interface. Perhaps, you can disabled block cache during a pipeline execution `void setBlockCacheEnabled(boolean
blockCacheEnabled) method`

Comment: Also, block cache can be configured to be persistent across restarts, see config key `hbase.bucketcache.ioengine`  and [doc](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#bc.deloy.modes) how to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Block cache is a read cache, and is stored in memory and will not recover when rs restart